# Initialize Eigen matrix from multiple existing matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an eigen Matrix `A` which has **4 rows & 2 columns**. Also I have two eigen Matrices `B` and `C` both have **2 rows and 2 columns**. I want to add that two Matrices one after other into my Matrix `A`. In order to do that one I used the following code which is apparently not correct. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
 MatrixXd A(4,4);
 MatrixXd B(2,2);
 MatrixXd C(2,2);
 B << 1,2,
      3,4;
 C << 5,6,
      7,8;
 A <<  B, // Error message:
       C;
```

Error message:

```
 XprType& Eigen::CommaInitializer<MatrixType>::finished() [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]: Assertion `((m_row+m_currentBlockRows) == m_xpr.rows() || m_xpr.cols() == 0) && m_col == m_xpr.cols() && "Too few coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)"' failed.
```

Required output:( 4 rows, 2 columns)

```
A = 1, 2,
    3, 4,
    5,6,
    7,8;
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong apart from two missing semicolons in the declarations of  `B` and `C`. I cannot reproduce the error. The code you posted works on my computer, and it gives the desired output.

Comment: More examples in the Eigen doc. [Advanced initialization](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)...

Comment: As @RHertel said, this works fine after adding two semicolons (and some stuff around to make it compile): https://godbolt.org/z/thq9Np

Comment: In your last edit you changed the size of `A` to `4 x 4`, but you expect a `4 x 2` sized output?!